# CLLocationManager not calling its delegate method

Tags: ios, core-location

I am developing an app which involves tracking the new location and updates to the server in X mins. I am stopping the location updating when the  time diff is equal to or greater than X mins, then sending to the server and then start updating the location if it is less than X mins. But the didUpdateToLocation delegate methos is not called when it is less than X mins.

I am posting my code here:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
    fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   if (theDiff > 10.0f || myDate == nil) 
        {
            [self stopUpdating];
         }
        else
        {
            [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }

}
```

Comment: have you added <CLLocation delegate> in your .h ?

Comment: Yes, I added in my .h file

Comment: i mean protocol? i.e UIViewController
< CLControllerDelegate>

Comment: set delegate in .m viewDidLoad

Comment: you have to write this [self.mLocationManager startUpdatingLocation]; line in your viewdidload method. review my answer. thanks

Comment: have you added this?
    [CLController sharedInstance].delegate = self;

Comment: No, let me give a try thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.,

```
//in your .h

CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

// Then synthesize it in your .m

@synthesize locationManager;

//in your viewDidLoad

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

This will call the method whwnever you move with your phone. You can check this by changing simulator locatin also.

Hope this helps., Thanks, happy coding.

Comment: Yes, I do have the same line in the viewDidLoad. But my question is to again update the location when the time diff is less than X mins.  I am sending the datas to the server after some mins and then updating the location again, which is working fine. But if it is less than X mins, it should again call the DidUpdateToLocation method.

Comment: ok., you have to write your time checking condition code out of the function. because once it called stopupdate, it will not able to call didUpdateToLocation method again, until it goes in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this in .m add this method , or if you have any other custom code post it

```
-(void)LocationWithTime
{
    [CLController sharedInstance].locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 100.0;
    [CLController sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    BOOL locationAccessAllowed = NO ;

    if( [CLLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)] )
    {
        locationAccessAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ;
    }
    if(locationAccessAllowed == YES)
    {

        [[CLController sharedInstance].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

}
```

this is the delegate method i have used -

```
-(void)newLocationUpdate:(NSString *)latvalue longValue:(NSString*)longvalue Error:(int) errCode
{



    DebugLog(@"LatLong values %@ %@", [UserContext sharedInstance].strLat, [UserContext sharedInstance].strLong);

    self.strLALat = latvalue;
    self.strLALong = longvalue;

    [[CLController sharedInstance].locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [CLController sharedInstance].delegate=nil ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from Apple API Documentation,

/*
 *  locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
 *
 *    This method is deprecated. If locationManager:didUpdateLocations: is
 *    implemented, this method will not be called.
 */

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_6, __MAC_NA, __IPHONE_2_0, __IPHONE_6_0);
```

Use the below delegate method instead,

/*
 *  locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
 *    locations is an array of CLLocation objects in chronological order.
 */

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_6_0);
```

This will work once you set the delegate.

Hope this helps.